# How to use mock with epel-7

Tags: fedora, rhel, chroot, epel

I have been trying to create a chroot for epel-7 using mock. Following this link:  http://miroslav.suchy.cz/blog/archives/2015/05/20/why_mock_does_not_work_on_el_6_and_el7_and_how_to_fix_it/index.html 
I changed my .cfg file. Now when I tr to create chroot, I get the following error:

```
 sudo ./create_chroot.sh epel-7
INFO: mock.py version 1.2.8 starting (python version = 2.7.8)...
Start: init plugins
INFO: selinux enabled
Finish: init plugins
Start: run
Start: clean chroot
Finish: clean chroot
Start: chroot init
INFO: calling preinit hooks
INFO: enabled root cache
INFO: enabled yum cache
Start: cleaning yum metadata
Finish: cleaning yum metadata
INFO: enabled ccache
Mock Version: 1.2.8
INFO: Mock Version: 1.2.8
Start: yum install
Error: Nothing to do
ERROR: Command failed. See logs for output.
```

As I already made the changes in /etc/mock/*.cfg file, I am not sure why am I still getting this error. Could you please help me figure out what other changes are necessary? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason was that the repos were not being configured properly. Changed the repos and everything worked fine. Thanks.